# How to export a notebook to google docs (without losing image quality)

Tags: export, notebooks, cells

I have a large notebook with many text cells some containing images and I need to import it to a google document that is editable. (so not pdf or html). So far no luck!

**Exporting to rich text format and then uploading causes a high level of degradation of the notebook's images.**

**Note:** I don't know how to upload a google doc from within Mathematica (and I don't believe this is possible), even though it's listed here as a service:

```
In[1]:= $EmbeddableServices

Out[1]= {"GoogleDocs", "GoogleForms", "GoogleSheets", "GoogleSlides", \
"Imgur", "SoundCloud", "Vimeo", "Vine", "YouTube"}
```

So I had to manually upload the .rtf export of the notebook manually in a browser. This is what the notebook's contents look like after export and upload:

[image]

The original notebook has the high resolution images that look like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it's scaling the images (poorly) before exporting them... make them bigger, play with the image mode etc (right click)?

Comment: Nah, they're definitely not the same resolution, can't even read the text...

Comment: Could you please post code or menu option even if it is obvious for those who are on different M versions or OS versions.

Comment: It would be good to have a minimal example and an algorithm to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Kuba, Of course but the problem is I can't make an example - sure I could create a notebook with an image then try to get the notebook into google docs for you, but I don't have your credentials.

Comment: @M.R. I see your point! I think you should assume like I do that exporting whole notebooks from Mathematica (styles and images intact) is impossible (unless you freeze the content into a pdf).

Comment: @M.R. I mean't something like minimal example of code to generate a notebook with any image, nothing deep but the less one have to do to reproduce your problem the more likely you will get attention. And by algorithm I mean't a list of steps. Before the edit there wasn't even mentioned that you are using built in services. Now it is but still maybe the problem is due to some subtlety in syntax which won't be caught due to the lack of code. Or maybe not. p.s. don't be cynical with those credentials, that obviously wasn't the case so you could've just asked or ignored me.